# Declaring a static method in one class and using it as a method of another class

Tags: c#, .net, static, extension-methods

I am doing the [Nerd Dinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm) for ASP.NET MVC and I met one construction in the C# language that seemed very strange. The title of this question is a bit vague, because I have trouble defining what this is. This also made it difficult for me to search about the topic, hence I decide to ask a question about it.

In the [Nerd Dinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm) I see the following code fragment:

```
public static class ControllerHelpers {

    public static void AddRuleViolations(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, IEnumerable<RuleViolation> errors) {

        foreach (RuleViolation issue in errors) {
            modelState.AddModelError(issue.PropertyName, issue.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And later they show:

```
//
// GET: /Dinners/Edit/2

public ActionResult Edit(int id) {

    Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);

    return View(dinner);
}

//
// POST: /Dinners/Edit/2

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues) {

    Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);

    try {

        UpdateModel(dinner);

        dinnerRepository.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id=dinner.DinnerID });
    }
    catch {

        ModelState.AddRuleViolations(dinner.GetRuleViolations());

        return View(dinner);
    }
}
```

The parts that puzzle me are:

```
public static void AddRuleViolations(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, IEnumerable<RuleViolation> errors)
```

and

```
ModelState.AddRuleViolations(dinner.GetRuleViolations());
```

It looks like you define the `AddRuleViolations` function in the `ControllerHelpers` class and then invoke it as if it was an instance function of the `ModelState` property. Is this observation correct? If yes, why would you need this? It looks very strange to me to define a method in one class as if it was a method of another class.

Note: `ModelState` is a property of the current class and not a class it self.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because it's an [*extension method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). That's what the "this" bit is at the start of the first parameter.

The idea of extension methods is that they allow you to effectively add functionality to existing classes. So if you have:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Reverse(this string text)
    {
        char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(chars);
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
string x = "hello world";
string y = x.Reverse();
```

that actually gets compiled as if you'd written:

```
string x = "hello world";
string y = StringExtensions.Reverse(x);
```

Extension methods have to be declared in top-level non-generic static classes. They're heavily used in LINQ.

Comment: Ah thanks. I couldn't find anything about it before without the extension methods keyword.

Answer (score 3):

That observation is indeed correct; this is an *extension method*, as noted by the `this` modifier before the parameter-type:

```
this ModelStateDictionary modelState
```

The compiler will then resolve calls to the method *looking* like an instance method of `ModelStateDictionary`, but note that it is still *actually* a static call - so:

```
obj.SomeStaticMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

is *actually* compiled as:

```
TheDeclaringType.SomeStaticMethod(obj, arg1, arg2);
```

which can result in oddities such as `obj` can be `null` *and the call will still work*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I were to call `obj.SomeStaticMethod` with `obj` being `null` and inside the function do `obj = new Object()`. And is it also possible to do that with value types?

Comment: `Matthijs` you can give it a value *inside the method*, but the parameter is not `ref` (and can't be), so it will **never** show back *outside* the method. `structs` can't be null (except `Nullable<T>`), but the same thing applies: since it isn't `ref`, any reassignment is not reflected outside the method.